# Exact copy of google form

Tags: forms, google-forms

How to create google form using url of google form send to me ? 
Suppose someone gave you google form for a survey and you like that form design, and you need similar form with some minor modification. So how can one clone it using the url ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just do it yourself from scratch...

Will be far easier and simpler.

Comment: I am creating it from scratch, but there is a method called re-usability.My question is, Does no such method exist ?

Comment: No, or else no one would be using Google's forms would they?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the URL from the URL bar, which should look like this

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/some-random-string/viewform
```

Replace `viewform` with `copy` so your URL should now look like this

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/some-random-string/copy
```

Comment: This won't work. The edit URL is different from the viewform URL of a form.

Comment: At the time I had tried it, it successfull worked for me in incognito. It's possible they changed the URLs since then